# Email signature appears stacked on Outlook 365 MacOS after sending email

Tags: macos, email, outlook, html-email, email-signature

`align="left"` and `style="float: left;"` works for Windows Outlook, website Outlook and other email clients, but doesn't work for the Desktop MacOS Outlook 365 app after sending an email.

Conditional formatting and media queries doesn't work either.

The signature looks correct when writing an email:
[Outlook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoBPV.jpg)

The signature stacks after sending the email:
[Outlook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNFu7.jpg)

Here's the code:

```
<table width="100%" style="width: 100%;max-width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" style="float: left;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>Test</p>
                            </td>
                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table align="left" style="float: left;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <!--<![endif]-->
                            <td>
                                <p>Test</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```